# How can I accept both two-digit and four-digit years with a single call to DateTime.ParseExact?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm calling .NET's `DateTime.ParseExact` with a custom format string along the lines of `"MM/dd/yyyy h:mmt"`. This string handles four-digit years but not two-digit years. Is there a way to handle both cases in a single ParseExact call? I've tried `"MM/dd/yy h:mmt"` and it only handles the two-digit case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can pass an array of format strings for the second parameter on this overload of [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) - this would include both the 2 and 4 year variants.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(myDateTime, 
                    new []{"MM/dd/yy h:mmt", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mmt"},
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Comment: Thanks; this is great. Are the formats tried in the order that they appear in the array? Would it be better to put the four-digit format first?

Comment: @WilliamGross - The documentation does not specify, but chances are that yes, they are tried in order. It would only be better to put the four-digit format first if most of the expected strings to parse will have four-digit years.

Answer (score 3):

Call the overload of `DateTime.ParseExact` that accepts an array of possible formats:

```
DateTime dt =
    DateTime.ParseExact(s, new[] { "MM/dd/yyyy h:mmt", "MM/dd/yy h:mmt" }, null, 0);
```

For the third argument, pass `null` or `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` if your date string is localized for the user's current culture; pass `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` if your date string is always in the U.S. format.

For the fourth argument, 0 is equivalent to `DateTimeStyles.None`.

See the [MSDN Library documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use the overloaded [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) that takes a string array of formats.

MSDN:

```
string[] formats= {"MM/dd/yyyy h:mmt", "MM/dd/yy h:mmt"};


var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                                        new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                        DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use the [appropriate overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
                               new[] { "MM/dd/yyy h:mmt", "MM/dd/yy h:mmt" },
                               new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                               DateTimeStyles.None);
```